# How to deny access to a certain page if the user is not logged in?

Tags: php

How can I deny access for a guest for certain pages?

For example, the edit profile page. Is there an easy way of doing it?

Answer (score 4):

Store user information on PHP's session.

If that information is not present on a certain request, then redirect the user to an **unaothorized** page.

For example:

`edit_profile.php` would have something like this:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if (!$_SESSION["user_data"]) {
        header("Location: unauthorized_error.php");
    }
?>
```

Of course, you would need a login page setting `user_data` on the session:

`login.php`:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $user = authorizeUsed($user, $pass);
    if ($user) {
        $_SESSION["user_data"] = $user;
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

When the user logs in succesfully, set a cookie. On sensitive pages, check for the cookie, and redirect away if not present. On logout, delete the cookie.

That's the rough schema, but there are many subtleties.

Comment: That solution is okay, but sessions are much more secure.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if ($_session['valid_user'] == false) {
        //Do stuff, maybe a redirect?

        header("Location: login.php");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($session[userid])){
    //Edit Profile Link
}
else
{
    //Not give link
}
```